How to move windows between spaces on 14.6
This is kind of like this Why can't I move the mini iTunes player between Spaces?
except it's an Xcode window on Sonoma 14.6
I have tried bringing the window to the edge on the side towards the space I want to move it to but snap to that space does not happen.
Minimizing the window to the tray, going to the destination space and yanking the window from the dock results in the switch to the space it was minimized from, then unminimizing it :-[
I can drag just fine on i9 mbp running 14.6.1 though but not on thos macstudio running 14.6
maybe there is some spaces configuration switch buried somewhere?

Can you drag windows of other applications between spaces?

No. Just the same the window disappears off screen instead of hanging at the border for a while before switch. Maybe the display scaling is to blame: on hdmi I don't even see the login prompt, only on usb-c that dell U4320 is useable.

Hmm, that was on the right edge. On the left edge it sits at the edge but it looks like if the edge has infinite resistance or no handler for spaces switch or whatever.

Does this condition persist across logouts/reboots? If the affected machine is a MacBook, does it persist with the external display disconnected?

macbook under 14 6 1 works fine. Gotta try the reboots.

Yes, the problem has survived upgrade to 16.7 which required reboot.

A trip to settings -> displays later I found that macos was thinking I have two dell displays. The solution was to disconnect hdmi cable and it works fine now.

Glad to hear. Please accept your answer for reference purposes.

It's weird. It does not work. I click on checkmark: spinner briefly appears, checkmark does not turn green, no error message.

Just the same issue in Chrome as in Safari -> can;t checkmark it, sorry.

To clarify, did you actually have two different cables connected to the same display, or was the HDMI cable only connected to the Mac?
